# ActionLink in PHP..?

Tags: php, .net, yii

I'm new with PHP programming. I would like to convert this .NET code:

> @Html.ActionLink("Registe", "Index", "Home")

to PHP (yii framework) but I can't find how. Someone can help me please?

Comment: do you use framework? or just plain php. If just plain php. just echo'<a href="index.html">Index</a>';

Comment: I'm using yii framework with bootstrap on Netbeans

Comment: That language is not PHP. Please elaborate what you've got there.

Comment: What language is `@Html.ActionLink`? Please edit that detail into your question.

Comment: @halfer I think it is asp.net

Comment: For yii framework, for URL management you can check here. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: @Html.ActionLink is .Net but I wanna convert it to PHP

Comment: I'm not that good with Yii, but I think the equivalent is: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/#hh0

Comment: Somy A, thanks, in that link there are exactally what I'm looking about.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code (in .NET) show a link.

By default PHP haven't a HTML generator, if you use a framework probably it have a HTML generator, and you can use it.

If you don't use a framework just do this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$text'.</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a language-based PHP implementation of a Razor (asp.net MVC) framework-based html helper, which doesn't exist. You'd have a better chance finding something similar to ActionLink in a PHP MVC framework like [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) or [Symfony](http://symfony.com/).